# Error with Bullet Gem Rails 4 and Uniform Notifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to use bullet gem to avoid N+1 queries in my website. 
I've used it until some months ago, then it stopped to work. I got this only today.

When I start my `localhost` I get this error message:

```
/Users/carcarlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require':/Users/carcarlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/uniform_notifier-1.12.0/lib/uniform_notifier/base.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
  <<~CODE
    ^/Users/carcarlo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/uniform_notifier- 1.12.0/lib/uniform_notifier/base.rb:38: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting keyword_end <script #{attributes_string}>/*<![CDATA[*/
     ^ target of repeat operator is not specified: /*]]>*/
```

it is clear that is an error in the file `base.rb` of the gem `uniform_notifier`, which is a dependency of `bullet`, but what can I do to get it working on my system?
I tried to force the installation of `uniform_notifier` to an older version (actual is 1.12.1) but it is locked to 1.12.0

This application is written using ruby 2.2.4 and rails 4.2.5

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it by using a lower version of bullet

```
gem 'bullet', '~> 5.7.6'
```

Comment: Works on rails 4.2 ruby 2.2.10 and Mac os Catalina